# How to add Word hyperlinks from Excel cells using VBA (hyperlink.add)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to use Excel VBA to make links in a Word document based upon Excel cell ranges. But when it gets to the `hyperlinks.add` line I get `"run-time error ‘450’: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"`.

Almost the exact same code works fine in Word VBA. I don't understand the error message. While I'm quite familiar with Excel VBA, Word VBA selections and ranges confuse me.

I made code examples below using strings instead of ranges, in each case the code inserts text successfully at the end of the `test.docx` document but while the Word VBA inserts text with a link below that, the Excel VBA code fails at the `hyperlinks.add` line.

Here is the Excel VBA Code that is not working:

```
Sub wordLinkFromExcelRanges()
Dim wApp As Word.Application, wDoc As Word.Document
Dim linkText As String, link As String
  linkText = "google"
  link = "http://www.google.com"
  Set wApp = New Word.Application
  wApp.Visible = True
  Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\test\test.docx")
  With wApp.Selection
    .EndKey 6, 0 'go to end of doc
    .TypeParagraph
    .TypeText "text without link"
    .TypeParagraph
    wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=link, _
    SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=linkText
  End With
  wApp.Quit
  Set wDoc = Nothing
  Set wApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is the Word VBA code that is working:

```
Sub wordLinkFromWord()
Dim wD As Document
Dim linkText As String, link As String
linkText = "google"
link = "http://www.google.com"
Set wD = ActiveDocument
With Selection
  .EndKey 6, 0
  .TypeParagraph
  .TypeText "text without link"
  .TypeParagraph
  wD.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=link, _
  SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=linkText
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the issue. You are referring to `Selection.Range` but I don't think anything is selected in this context.

You can try this instead:

```
Sub wordLinkFromExcelRanges()
    Dim wApp        As Word.Application: Set wApp = New Word.Application
    Dim wDoc        As Word.Document
    Dim linkText    As String: linkText = "google"
    Dim link        As String: link = "http://www.google.com"

    wApp.Visible = True
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\test\test.docx")
    With wApp.Selection
      .EndKey 6, 0
      .TypeParagraph
      .TypeText "text without link"
      .TypeParagraph
      wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range, Address:=link, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=linkText
    End With
    wApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Ryan, for your help. Yes, you figured it out and posted almost the same time I did.  I'll leave my solution, but give you the credit for helping.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. Glad you got it sorted out :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: the `"Selection"` in the problem line should be `"wApp.Selection"`

wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wApp.Selection.Range, Address:=link, _
SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=linkText

The process of making a minimal example helped me -- maybe the simple example will help others too.